# jQuery live alternative (is there only on()?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-delegation

I was using live() for using my function at the ajax datas.

just like: `$(".mydiv").live('click', function(){ alert("blablabla"); })`

It was working fine, if I click on ajax datas which is '.mydiv'

but 'on' method doesn't support this?

```
$(".removebet").on('click',' i', function(){alert("blablabla");});
```

It doesn't work, if "i" is come from ajax datas.
Why? How can I solve this?

Comment: both of them are entirely different

Comment: Does `.removebet` also come from ajax?

Comment: you should declare an element that was already in the DOM before any Ajax call

Comment: Little help: your first example is equivalent to `$(document).on('click', '.mydiv', function () { //blah })`, but you should simply read the jQuery documentation.

Comment: Read the jQuery documentation to learn how to convert `.live` to `.on`: http://api.jquery.com/live/. I also recommend to have a look at http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/.

Answer (score 2):

The selector for the elements that you want to bind using `.on` needs to exist when `.on` is called.  That is to say that if `.removebet` does not exist when `.on` is called (it sounds like it doesn't), `.on` won't bind to anything.

Your safest bet would be to use

```
$(document).on("click", ".removebet i" ...
```

Ideally pick an existing selector that is closer to the target descendants than `document`.

Comment: I've found the problem. I can't ajax post with 'on'.